# CakePhp 3 : server php not found

Tags: server, cakephp-3.0

i'm trying cakephp v3 for a test, so i have install cake with composer, and i can't launch the server as requested by the tutorial.

When i do `bin/cake server` in the app folder, i get this response:

```
bin/cake: line 39: exec: php not found
```

I tried with ./bin/cake but it's the same.

For information, i have wamp on my computer and the authorization for bin are rwxr-xr-x.

Any idea on how fix it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the PHP directory to your path. On the command line (e.g. in a batch file), it would look like this:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\wamp\path\php
```

if in doubt, it's the directory containing the php.exe.